# One Query to power duplicate worksheets with a live data connection?

Tags: optimization, query-optimization, tableau-api

Tableau version: 10.2.5 Desktop

I have a dashboard showing a map of the lower 48, Hawaii, and Alaska. To achieve this, I made the lower 48 map and then duplicated focusing only on Hawaii and Alaska.

We use a live connection to Dremio.

When analyzing the dashboard, I see 3 separate queries being kicked off for these maps. I am wondering if there is a way to have only one query kick off to power the duplicated map worksheets. Each of the queries is processing through the same data set and returning the same amount of results.

Essentially, we would see some performance gain as there would be one query running instead of three allowing other queries to run in parallel.

As I understand, this is the standard way to build maps without having to zoom out too far to fit everything in one view. To my knowledge, this is how Tableau is supposed to operate....one query being kicked off for one worksheet on the dashboard. Receiving some pressure and push back about this performance.

I don't have a workbook to provide as this more of a function of how Tableau operates with databases using live connections.

I've researched this quite a bit, but have come up unsuccessful and wondering if I'm just missing something, or is this just how it behaves?

Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: Take a look at a data extract. It will speed up your performance and significantly reduce the number of queries issued to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, a data extract is not an option as it needs to be a live connection. We have two data sources as it is: 1) data extract that serves as the driving extract (fact table with id's that scopes down the data on certain dimensions selected) and then the live connection that kicks off queries based on the the input values from the extract. It has to be live due to the size and number of records which is in the millions and can bleed into the billions.